# RESTful call to HTTPS server from java client

Tags: rest, https

I have configured a Bobcat server on my local machine that listens to HTTP and HTTPS requests on ports 8000 and 8001 respectively.

While I can call a RESTful service using HTTP from a Java client -

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8000/helloworld");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

I am not able to call the same service on port 8001, using HttpsURLConnection objects. Do I need to configure SSL or get security certificates or something?

My main motive is to work on the RESTful service, I'm using a web client (JSP) to simply test the service. Can someone help me call the service endpoint using HTTPS?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I had problems hitting the HTTPS server because there was no security certificate that had been defined for the server. I just had to test my service with HTTP.

My teammate pointed out that HTTPS wont be working as there were no security certificates, hence no encryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RESTClient plugin on Firefox for testing it.
It allows you to make all GET,POST requests to an endpoint.

Download Link : https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/

Similar plugins are available for other browsers as well.
I have tried :

Advanced Rest Client : Google Chrome